# Where has my Mark Edge Seam button gone?

Tags: shortcut

[image]I'm using blender 2.79 and have not modified any of its code, but for some reason I have to use the space bar and search for "Mark Seam" in order to use this function. I should not that I don't see it in blender 2.8 either. Am I missing something? I thought it was always under the Edge's Menu!

Menu: Mesh ‣ Edges ‣ Mark Seam/Clear Seam is gone!

Has anyone had this problem, or know how to fix it?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add an image of your interface.

Comment: In my build, it's in a sub-menu: Edge Menu > Edge Data You're right.. I think that's a recent change..

Comment: @Robin Betts You are right! Thank you for showing me da way! I get it now.

Comment: In Edit mode Press ctrl+E there you can find it

Comment: It's also available in the <kbd>U</kbd> (unwrap) menu at the bottom, below the unwrap methods. However "Clear Seam" seems to be missing from the 2.8 search system at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. But as @Robin Betts pointed out. The Mark Seams function has moved to the **Edge Data** Sub-menu.

Thank you @Robin Betts !